# Monitor doesn't wake up after sleep

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I am using ASUS monitor connected to Windows7 laptop using HDMI cable and it is working fine. But when the system goes to sleep and wakeup,  **monitor doesn't wake up after sleep**

I got to manually turn off and turn on the monitor to make it work.

Comment: does it allow multiple input sources? perhaps it's switching to another one after the pc is sleeping but doesn't keep a look out for new inputs showing up again, just to check you could push the source button on the monitor to see if it switches to the working one. Also it might help others to know the model of your monitor and make and model of your graphics card are too.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I have a non-spec HDMI cable causing this issue and I replaced with the Genuine one and it is working now.

Comment: What is a "non-spec" cable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in driver as many people wrote. Update drivers helped to me.

1. Find and open Device manager.
2. Show all Display adapters.
3. Right click on your video card.
4. Update driver.
   Second monitor woke up after updating drivers.